# Chartjs. Como ajustar a altura do gráfico de acordo com o tamanho da tabela? Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic, chartjs

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em Ionic 3, em que consumo dados de uma API e mostro os dados em um gráfico na horizontal. A quantidade de dados retornada pela API não é padrão, então as vezes a altura previamente setada no CSS, não é sufuciente ([Veja aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCIYg.png) e [aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRjCo.png)). E não estou conseguindo fazer com o que o gráfico se ajuste a altura. Eu ja tentei atribuir `height: auto`, mas o chart.js insere a altura default.

Meu HTML:

```
<div class="chart-container" >
<canvas #barCanvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Meu CSS

```
.chart-container{
position: relative;
margin: auto;
height: 110vh;
width: 80vw;
}
```

Meu JS

```
private loadChart(){

var backgroundColor = [];

if (this.barChart) {
    this.barChart.destroy();
}
for (let x = 0; x < this.servicos.length; x ++) {
    backgroundColor[x] = this.randomColor();        
}

this.barChart = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: this.temp.labels,
        datasets: [{                
            label:this.consulta.Unidade,
            data: this.temp.valores,
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
            borderWidth: 0                
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            xAxes:[{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }

});
}
```

Eu tentei mudar o valor de `height` comparando o tamanho da tabela antes de criar. Funcionou na primeira vez que entrei na página, mas eu tenho um filtro que faz uma nova requisição e cria um novo gráfico, mas a propriedade `height` é atribuida um valor padrão do chart.js

```
if(this.servicos.length <= 10){
    document.getElementById("chart-container").style.height = "300px"
}
if(this.servicos.length > 10 ){
    document.getElementById("chart-container").style.height = "900px"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava no filtro. Eu estava usando uma modal que enviava os paraâmetros para outra view `this.navCtrl.push(IndicadoresPage, {consulta: consulta});`. Eu mudei para `this.viewCtrl.dismiss(consulta)` e capturei os dados com `onDidDismiss()`.

Depois eu troquei para `chart.canvas.parentNode.style.height = 'XXXpx'` ao invés de mudar a `div`